# Why position relative and float left causing multilevel navigational drop down behave unexpectedly?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to design a multilevel navigational menu in HTML and CSS but have not been able to stack the list items inside ul.sub1 on top of each other. They definitely seem to obey the rules defined for ul#navmenu li but that's definitely not what I expected . The list items under ul.sub1 should be stacked on top of each other instead of being aligned horizontally one after the other. What is the logical error that I am making? Please explain as I am a newbie to CSS Navigational Menus. Here is my HTML code snippet :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<style>
    *{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
        box-sizing: border-box;  <!--Specifies an element should have padding and border included in element's total width and height-->
        <!--Content Box is the default value for the height and width properties-->
    }  
    <!--Resetter rules for browsers-->
    #bodyContainer {
    }
    body {
        border:black 2px solid;
        background-color : grey;
        padding:5px;
    }
    div#header {
        margin:10px auto;
        background-color : red;
        width:70%;
        -webkit-border-radius:15px;
        -moz-border-radius:15px;
        border-radius:15px;
    }
    div#header1 {   
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:80px;
    }
    div#header2 {
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:80px;
    }
    ul#navmenu , ul.sub1{
        list-style-type:none;
        background-color:#444;                  
        margin-bottom:20px;
        border-radius:5px;
    }
    ul#navmenu li {
        border:black 1px solid;
        background:yellow;
        border-radius:5px;
        height:30px;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:30px;
        width:33.33%;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
    }
    ul#navmenu a {
        text-decoration:none;
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }
    ul.sub1 li {
        border:black 1px solid;
        background:yellow;
        border-radius:5px;
        height:30px;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:30px;
        width:100px;
        positipn:absolute;
        display:block;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bodyContainer">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header1"><h1>Welcome</h1></div><div id="header2"><h1>You Get to choose better !! </h1></div>           
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentHeader">
            <p>You Select ... We Serve </p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul id="navmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                    <ul class="sub1">
                        <li><a href="#">Home1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fashions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>WebApp Version Numbered v1.0. All rights Reserved. </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't really write what's wrong with the code. can you write what is it you tried to do?
You wanted the items in navmenu to flow (not sure if thats the write term) vertically?

Comment: I have edited the question details. Please do have a look . Thanks in advance.

Comment: In short, the problem is with the floats, remove them and fix the other stuff to support what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "li" elements you're having problems with have their width overridden by the parent's "li", because of the higher specificity of the "ul#navmenu li" versus "ul.sub1 li"

So either add:

```
width: 100% !important;
```

to your "ul.sub1 li" rule, or make the same rule of higher specificity, for example:

```
ul#navmenu li ul.sub1 li
```

and the width of the "ul.sub1 li" width will be used.

You can learn more about CSS specificity in this smashing article: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/